# How to disable ribbon while VBA code is running

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

I need to cancel button clicks on a Custom Ribbon if code is already running.

The problem: although I can disable the button, clicks are still 'registered' and even though disabled, the corresponding code runs once for each button click.

```
Public Sub OnActionButton(control As IRibbonControl)

    ' The following approach fails to prevent code from running
    If Not globalEnabled Then Exit Sub

    ' The following approach fails to prevent code from running
    Dim goodToGo as Boolean
    GetEnabled control, goodToGo
    If Not goodToGo Then Exit Sub


    ' *********************************************************
    ' Code Below Here Should NOT Run If Button Was Clicked 
    ' While globalEnabled = False (i.e. code already running)
    ' *********************************************************

    ' Disable the Ribbon
    globalEnabled = False
    RibbonInvalidate

    Select Case control.id
        Case "btnID"
            ' doSomething
    End Select

    ' Re-enable the ribbon
    globalEnabled = True
    RibbonInvalidate

End Sub
```

Edit: For what its worth, this is how I disable the button:

```
Public Sub GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
' Called by RibbonInvalidate
    Select Case control.id
        Case "btnID"
            enabled = globalEnabled 
    End Select 
End Sub
```

I can imagine that the first click runs as expected, the second click (which is made while the code corresponding to the first click is running) is 'queued' until the first click is completed. At that time globalEnabled is True again so the checks are ineffective.

I guess I could hide the custom ribbon tab (or replace it with a dummy tab) - but is that really necessary?

Is there an elegant way to cancel a button press?

---

**Edit:**

I could add a bunch of doEvents to the code, but slows things down too much.

**Edit2:**

If I display a message box during code execution then, for some reason, it seems that things work as expected...

In fact... if I display a message box then I don't even need the early exit logic - so weird!

Comment: That's kind of just how a responsive UI *works*. Why should it matter if you re-enter the button handler and immediately exit at your re-entry flag?

Comment: @Comintern Unless I'm missing something... I really don't mind that it enters the button handler, but the code should only run once... Setting globalEnabled to false does NOT cause the subsequent button presses to exit early on my PC. I think this is because when the first click is finished the globalEnabled becomes True again (by necessity) and that is how this all falls apart...

Comment: I'm having some difficulty following the logic, here. The code you show disables then re-enables the Ribbon in the same procedure. The Windows interface caches user actions (keyboard, mouse) if they can't be executed right away because something else is executing that blocks them. Since Word/Office is *synchronous* (for the most part) it follows that the mouse clicks are being cached? I don't think there's any way around that, unless there's something in the Windows APIs.

Comment: @CindyMeister well let's take a step back - assume I have a macro that takes 5 mins to run AND it is triggered by a click on a ribbon button. It only needs 1 click, the code runs... user clicks again, code runs a second time... now 10 minutes will pass before the code completes... user decides to click many times... now code will run for 30 odd minutes...  how do I disable the button so that scenario can be avoided?

Comment: @CindyMeister surely.... if the buttons are disabled (and I can confirm they are greyed out) then the button handler should not even fire... but... on my PC it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, main thing was adding doEvents (or a message box) at the end.

```
Public Sub OnActionButton(control As IRibbonControl)

    ' Disable the Ribbon
    globalEnabled = False
    RibbonInvalidate

    Select Case control.id
        Case "btnID"
            ' doSomething
    End Select

    ' Re-enable the ribbon
    doEvents                     ' <-- Adding this fixed the issue for me
    ' msgbox "finished"          ' <-- also works, but pretty annoying ;-)
    globalEnabled = True
    RibbonInvalidate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Im late to the party, but are you declaring GlobalEnabled as a global variable?  Because from my understanding and testing (on a similar problem) if it is not explicitly declared as global, each time the ribbon button is clicked, a local variable of GlobalEnabled is created rather than using the value set in the prior run of the macro.